# Hibernate/HSQLDB: User lacks priviledges to create constraints

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb, dbunit

I am using `HSQL` along with `DBUnit` to run my unit tests. So far, I can start `HSQL` from a script which creates a new schema, then `Hibernate` creates the tables and `DBUnit` add the data in these tables. However, I keep having these errors logs:

```
2013-10-10 09:38:05,559 INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2013-10-10 09:38:05,563 ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table dbo.MY_TABLE drop constraint FK58568EF941C829A
2013-10-10 09:38:05,563 ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: DBO.MY_TABLE
2013-10-10 09:38:05,564 ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table dbo.MY_TABLE drop constraint FK58568EF12A53C22
2013-10-10 09:38:05,564 ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: DBO.MY_TABLE
2013-10-10 09:38:05,592 ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table dbo.MY_TABLE add constraint FK58568EF941C829A foreign key (id_my_other_table) references dbo.MY_OTHER_TABLE
2013-10-10 09:38:05,592 ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - The table data is read only in statement [alter table dbo.MY_TABLE add constraint FK58568EF941C829A foreign key (id_my_other_table) references dbo.MY_OTHER_TABLE]
```

It seems that only constraints cannot be created for some reason.
I checked that the tables have been properly created and the data added with `org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing`. I wanted to have a look in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` but the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is empty. Could it be the reason or these errors? Something else? As I'm using the user `SA` which has all priviledges, he should be able to create constraints?

Regarding my configuration:

`Hibernate` 4.1.10.Final

`HSQLDB` 2.3.0

`DBUnit` 2.4.9

In my `beans.xml` I have:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:initdata" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>primobox.demat.model.sql</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">auto</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.defaultNChar">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

My `initdata.properties`

```
version=2.0.0
modified=yes
files_readonly=true
```

Comment: I'm having your troubles too. I've tried also with H2 in memory and with Mysql.. I think that it causes the problems I'm having running multiple tests..

Comment: I've found this.. http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#fkconstraintviolation

Comment: Thanks for the link I didn't saw it in the faq. However it didn't solve my problem. @fredt answer did !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One likely cause is Hibernate sees a different, empty database that has no tables.

The line below connects to a relative path. Change it to an absolute path here and anywhere else you connect to the database and it should work.

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:initdata" />
```

The other problem is you have set up files_readonly in the .properties file. Do not create a properties file and let the engine create the database when you first connect. Delete any existing database.

Comment: Removing the `files_readonly` plus changing the path of the initialisation script solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was solved using this line:

```
sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
```

Comment: It's one of the properties from my `beans.xml` dbUnit evoled quite a lot since then. I haven't had a weird error for quite a while now ^^